# tkinter past text keeping font

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts, copy-paste, text-widget

I have a tkinter text widget and I would be able to copy a text from excel (as exemple) and past it into my text widget 'tC' and keep the font define in excel, like bold, italics, color ect.. for now i just get the text black and basic. I don't get if it's just the display or the font is not past. Thanks you

Here is how I create my text label:

```
windPop = tk.Toplevel()
windPop.attributes('-topmost', 'true')
windPop.wm_geometry("600x600")
frm1 = tk.LabelFrame(windPop)
frm1.pack(side=tk.TOP)

labT = tk.Label(frm1, text="Titre", bg="white", height=1, width=10)
labT.grid(row=0,column=1)
tT = tk.Text(frm1, height=1, width=10, bg="white")
tT.grid(row=0,column=2)

frm3 = tk.LabelFrame(windPop)
frm3.pack()

labT = tk.Label(frm3, text="Genre", bg="white", height=1, width=10)
labT.grid(row=0,column=1)
sexMail = tk.StringVar(frm3)
sexMail.set("neutre")
tG = tk.OptionMenu(frm3, windows.genreMailVariable, *windows.genreMail)
tG.grid(row=0,column=2)

frm2 = tk.LabelFrame(windPop)
frm2.pack()

labC = tk.Label(frm2, text="Corps du mail", bg="white", width=20)
labC.grid(row=0,column=1)
tC = tk.Text(frm2, height=30, width=40, bg="white")
tC.grid(row=0,column=2)

bb = tk.Button(windPop, text='valider creation', width=20)
bb.pack(pady=10, side=tk.BOTTOM)
bb.configure(command=lambda w=windows, corp=tC, titre=tT, genre=sexMail, par=windPop :self.valid_creation(w, corp, titre, genre, par))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for this in tkinter. Tkinter can't get font information from the clipboard.